# Ansible: Create identical list items where number depending on value of another variable

Tags: ansible

I want to compose a body for the Ansible URI module.

Therefor I need a dictionary which I tried to create with with set_fact.

This dictionary shall contain a list of items with identical key/value pairs.

How often the the key/value pair has to be added is defined in another variable, lets say number_of_functions.

When number_of_functions is 5 the expected result shall contain the same key/value pair 5 times:

```
composed_body:
  functions:
  - functionType: something
  - functionType: something
  - functionType: something
  - functionType: something
  - functionType: something
```

Then I would use the composed_body variable within the URI body with "body_format: json" which would give:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "functionType": "something"
    },
    {
      "functionType": "something"
    },
    {
      "functionType": "something"
    },
    {
      "functionType": "something"
    },
    {
      "functionType": "something"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried something with jinja2/range/regex replace but I never got a valid YAML/JSON structure.

Any idea how to create the list entries depending on the value of number_of_functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        composed_body: "{{ _composed_body|from_yaml }}"
      vars:
        number_of_functions: 5
        _composed_body: |-
          functions:
          {% for i in range(number_of_functions) %}
          - functionType: something
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  composed_body:
    functions:
    - functionType: something
    - functionType: something
    - functionType: something
    - functionType: something
    - functionType: something
```